# Regex: New line after each word or each number

Tags: regex

I have 2 lines.

`1 2 3 4`

`one two three`

The input should be:

- `1`
- `2`
- `3`
- `4`
- `one`
- `two`
- `three`

I try this regex, doesn't work: 
Search: `^(\d+)(\w+)\s+$`
Replace by: `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
\s*(\w+)
```

The substitution is:

```
$1\n
```

https://regex101.com/r/eJBFNX/2

`(\w+)` - the first capturing group, will match both numbers and alphanumeric sequences(words) separated with *non-word* characters

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're using Notepad++. Try this:

```
Find what:    (\w+)( )
Replace with: \1\n
```

This looks for a group of one-or-more letters and numbers, followed by a space,
and replaces that by the matched word/number and a newline.

Comment: @JustMe: You may use a shorter one identical to above: `"\w+ "` (with no quotes) to replace with `$&\n`